# javafx - controlsfx - CheckTreeView - click on CheckBoxTreeItem graphic node is checking the checkbox

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

Tested on:

- win10 64
- ControlsFx v11.1.1

When I will add a graphic node (ImageView) into CheckBoxTreeItem it behaves as a checkbox (when clicked on). In the example below, I have added wide icons to showcase the issue. Just click on the empty space between checkbox and value and you will see the checkbox will get checked/unchecked.

[image]

I would expect the clicking on the ImageView to just select the row.
Just like in this picture:
[image]

here is a minimalistic code example:

```
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBoxTreeItem;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.controlsfx.control.CheckTreeView;

public class App extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    // prepare icons for the tree items
    ImageView imgIcon1 = new ImageView();
    imgIcon1.setFitWidth(64);
    imgIcon1.setFitHeight(16);

    ImageView imgIcon2 = new ImageView();
    imgIcon2.setFitWidth(64);
    imgIcon2.setFitHeight(16);

    // prepare tree items
    CheckBoxTreeItem<String> root = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("Root");
    CheckBoxTreeItem<String> item1 = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("Jonathan", imgIcon1);
    CheckBoxTreeItem<String> item2 = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("Eugene", imgIcon2);

    // add items to the root
    root.getChildren().add(item1);
    root.getChildren().add(item2);
    root.setExpanded(true);

    // Create the CheckTreeView with the data
    CheckTreeView<String> checkTreeView = new CheckTreeView<>(root);

    // show the scene with the tree
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(checkTreeView, 200, 100));
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

Any idea how to change the behavior from checking the checkbox to selecting the row?

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem? That will make it much easier for us to try potential solutions, as we'll be able to just copy-and-paste your code as is. Currently, we'd have to write quite a bit of infrastructure to reproduce your problem. Also, you should specify which version of _ControlsFX_ you're using.

Comment: thank you @Slaw for pointing out the issue with my question. I have edited it.

Comment: thanks for the example :) Looks like unrelated to controlsfx - same behavior for core tree with checkBoxTreeItem and checkBoxTreeCell. Actually, the same for a standalone checkBox: clicking anywhere onto text/graphic toggles its selection. You might need to implement a custom cell that layouts the graphic separately from the checkbox.

Comment: btw: you must not try to use the same node in different parents: typically, you get an exception when doing it. Here the imageView is silently moved to the next cell, that is only the last visible cell really has the graphic.

Comment: thank you @kleopatra, I have updated the example with your comments, any chance you can show me how to implement the custom cell you were mentioning?

Comment: have a look at CheckBoxTreeCell and it's parent DefaultTreeCell: the former contains the update logic and the wiring to the checkBox (just c&p), the latter uses a HBox if the item is of type Node (which it never should be, btw, but at the time of its design it was .. thought of as cool support ;) - use such a HBox always with children (checkBox, item's graphic), then set this HBox as graphic of the cell.

Comment: thx @kleopatra, but unfortunately, when I want to create classes MyTreeCell (that would replace DefaultTreeCell) and MyCheckBoxTreeCell that will extend MyTreeCell I am getting into an issue that I need to reuse the class named CellUtils which is protected :(
Any other ideas on how to make this think work?

Comment: copy that as well ..